# How to get NULL values in csv for MySQL with fputcsv?

Tags: php, mysql, null, fputcsv

In PHP I'm using the `fputcsv` function to produce a comma separated file for import in a MySQL-table  (using  `LOAD DATA INFILE`) :

```
fputcsv($fcsv, array( 
    $id,
    $name,
    $optional
));
```

`$optional` can be empty so in MySQL this should be `NULL`

In the MySQL documentation I read that to import a `NULL` value, it should be defined as `\N` in the csv-file.

But the `fputcsv` function puts quotes around it, so MySQL thinks it's the *string* `"\N"`.

Is there a solution for this, or should I forget about using `fputcsv` ?

Comment: did you try `"\\N"` ?

Comment: yes, makes no difference, fputcsv still puts double quotes around it

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hack, but you could just str_replace the "\N" with \N in the output:

```
//open temporary datastream for CSV output    
$fp = fopen("php://temp", "w");

//assuming $data is an array of arrays each of which is a record with \N 
//in place of nulls
foreach($data as $line) {
  fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

//read data back in to a string
rewind($fp);
$csv_data = fgets($fp);

//replace "\N" with \N
$csv_data = str_replace('"\N"', '\N', $csv_data);

//save to file
file_put_contents($csv_file_path, $csv_data);
```

Might not be the most memory-efficient either so be careful for large datasets, but should work...